# Four groups of order 20 that are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Give four groups of order 20 that are not isomorphic.

I know the integers under addition mod 20 is one group of order 20, but what would three other groups of order 20 that are not isomorphic to it?

Comment: Here's another: the dihedral group or order $20$.

Comment: Forget my last comment, please.  It's too late in Germany now ...

Answer (score 9):

- We can easily find two groups of order $20$ (even two abelian groups of order $20$) that are not isomorphic: $$\mathbb Z_{20} \not\cong \mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{10}$$
  We know this because $$\mathbb Z_{mn} \cong \mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n \iff \gcd(m, n) = 1$$
- Also add the Dihedral group of order $20$: The group of symmetries of
  a regular decagon.
- You might want to visit the Groupprops website, now or in the future.
  It comes in very handy for problems of this sort, but also as a handy
  reference for group theory (definitions, theorems, classification of
  groups, etc): [Groupprops: groups of order
  20](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_20).

There are exactly FIVE non-isomorphic groups of order $20$. The two not already mentioned are the dicyclic group [$\mathrm{Dic}_{20},$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group%3aDic20) and the general affine group [$\mathrm{GA}(1, 5)$.](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/General_affine_group%3aGA%281,5%29)

Comment: There's also the dihedral group of order $20,$ which is non-abelian, so different from the cyclic group of order $20$ and the direct product of cyclic groups you mention. The other two involve non-trivial semi-direct products.

Comment: Yes, @Cameron, as noted on the dihedral group. Thanks for the added reference to the semi-direct products.

Comment: You are welcome. (+1)

Comment: @amWhy: Another UV on the way! +1

Comment: hersch - Is there a reason you haven't accepted the answer? You can accept an answer even though it's on hold, or a duplicate, if it's been helpful! ;-)