# Identify the presentation of groups

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm trying to classify all groups of order $20$. I get two group presentation and want to identify isomorphism type. I think one of these isomorphic to $D_{10}$ and other isomorphic to $Dic_5$. Can anyone tell me to find exactly which one isomorphic to $D_{10}$ and other isomorphic to $F_5$? I might get wrong presentations.

These are my two presentation,

$$G_1 =\langle r,a,b\mid r^5=1,a^2=b^2=1,r^{3}br^{-3}=b,r^{3}ar^{-3}=a\rangle$$

and

$$G_2 =\langle r,s\mid r^5=1,s^4=1,r^3sr^{-3}=s\rangle $$

Thank you.

Comment: You should note that a lot of the relations given can be translated as certain elements commuting. Try to play around a bit with them and see if perhaps other elements turn out to also commute

Comment: In $G_{2}$, do you agree that $s\in C_{G}(r^{3})=C_{G}(r)$, which means $o(rs)=20$? So $G_{2}$ is cyclic.

Comment: @user1729 Can you explain how $G_1$ is isomorphic to $D_{10}$?

Comment: @Ash I got it thank you. Can you explain anything about $G_1$?

Comment: @Alhabud $G_1$ is *not* isomorphic to $D_{10}$; it surjects onto the infinite dihedral group (add $r=1$ as a relation), and so isn't even finite! Where did you get the presentation from?

Comment: GAP confirms that $G_2$ is $\Bbb Z_{20}$.

Comment: `TzGoGo` does nothing to the presentation defining $G_1$, so, presumably, there is no straightforward way of showing whether it's $F_5$.

Comment: Oops! I forgot about Frobenius groups; I thought you meant the free group of rank five!

Comment: Still: `StructureDescription` is inconclusive on $G_1$. But that's because it is, indeed, infinite; see @user1729's comment above.

Comment: @Alhabud I’ll tell you how we conclude that $G_{1}$ is not isomorphic to $D_{10}$. So by the same discussion $o(ra)=o(rb)=10$ and we know $\langle ra \rangle$ and $\langle rb \rangle$ are different subgroups isomorphic to $C_{10}$, but we know that $D_{10}$ has only one (unique) subgroup isomorphic to $C_{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small collection of posts about the classification of groups of order $20$. It is too long for a comment.

1. [Find four groups of order 20 not isomorphic to each other.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577917/find-four-groups-of-order-20-not-isomorphic-to-each-other?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Four groups of order 20 that are not isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582157/four-groups-of-order-20-that-are-not-isomorphic?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [Classifying groups of order $20$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477122/classifying-groups-of-order-20?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. [Classification of groups of order $20$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442057/classification-of-groups-of-order-20?noredirect=1&lq=1)
5. [Must a group of order $20$ have an element of order $10$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4631638/must-a-group-of-order-20-have-an-element-of-order-10?noredirect=1&lq=1)
6. [Prove G is a nonabelian group of order 20](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645219/prove-g-is-a-nonabelian-group-of-order-20)
7. [How can I show that $G$ is non abelian of order 20?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757852/how-can-i-show-that-g-is-non-abelian-of-order-20)

The last one has the presentation for $F_5$, or sometimes denotes Frobenius $F_{20}$, namely
$$
G=\langle x,y|x^4=y^5=1,x^{-1}yx=y^2\rangle
$$